# Passing PHP Session ID as a POST parameter

Tags: php, forms, security, session

In light of my recent issue ([PHP - Session lost/emptied on form post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9730845/php-session-lost-emptied-on-form-post)), the session ID almost by random regenerates itself upon a form being posted (login -> add item to basket OR add item to basket -> login), resulting in the session data being lost. A work around was brought to light that I could pass the session ID as a hidden input to force the session ID to maintain itself. Is this a practical fix? And would this open me up to any vulnerabilities?

Please note that my website is run on a shared server.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't affect the level of your security. The session ID is stored as a cookie on the user's browser and you propose saving it in the HTML source. Either way, the end user or a malicious entity using a network sniffer will be able to access this data. So you can use it if it makes your job easier.

Answer (score 0):

I'll take a stab in the dark and guess that when you're submitting the form to a different subdomain, i.e. you're on http://www.example.com, and you're submitting to https://secure.example.com or the like.

If so, you need to make sure that the session cookie domain is set to use all subdomains of your website, not just your current one.  You can check that with:

```
ini_get('session.cookie_domain');
// if this outputs something like "www.example.com" and you're submitting to
// "somethingelse.example.com", here's your problem.
```

If it's not set properly, you can set it either in php.ini or in your scripts:

```
ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');  // or...
session_set_cookie_params(ini_get('session.cookie_lifetime'), ini_get('session.cookie_path'), '.example.com');

session_start();
```

... alternatively, you can just make sure that you're using the same subdomain when you submit the form as there's rarely a good reason to use a different one in this context.

Or your problem could be completely unrelated.  Worth checking out in any case.

But, as @Kaustubh Karkare said, the security of passing session variables through your form is identical to passing them through cookies.  And as for practicality, it's a perfectly reasonable, if not often used, way to pass session ids around.

Comment: I haven't set this, but I post to the same domain, same file (using a GET pagination structure). As this is shared hosting, could it be possible that this is the cause?

Comment: Can't really tell without seeing your page where the problem exists, but if you're posting to $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] then this is not likely to be the issue... I just know that when I dealt with this issue (losing session) the issue was subdomain related.

Comment: Should I just set ini_set('session.cookie_domain', '.example.com');  as a precautionary measure?

Comment: run a test first.  `if ($_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'] != $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) { echo 'potential problem [domain mismatch]: '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_URI'].' != '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']; } if (!preg_match('/^\./', $scd = ini_get('session.cookie_domain')) && $scd != $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) { echo 'potential problem [cookie domain]: ['.$scd.'] & ['.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].']'; }` ... if $scd is empty, it may or may not be the problem, but setting it as you suggested as a precautionary measure will at least ensure that it's set the way you want it.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of posting it, go to your action page from your form and use this

```
<?php

//let's start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION['whateveryouwanttocallit'] = session_id()

?>
```

So basically don't post it at all....

You can check it by the following:

```
<?php print_r($_SESSION)?>
```

And can confirm it to: `<?php echo session_id()?>`

In answer to your question however, this is not a good work around.

By posting a session id to your session, you're just creating a duplicate of the information and naming it whatever you want, the session ID is already in your session.

Also, if you're intending to use your session ID in a hidden input as a form of cookie to ensure they information on that user isn't lost, the problems will be:

1. The session with this newly created session id will also get wiped.
2. Even if it stayed, the session id will have been regenerated and so be a different string.